# Identify all elements with specific number of decimal places in R

Tags: r

I want to identify all elements with exactly 2 decimal places but i have no idea how to handle that problem...

Example:

```
x<-data.frame(col1=c("A","B","C"),
              col2=c("1.32","1.235","1.22"))
```

As a result i only would like to have the corresponding elements from col1, in this case: A C

Comment: succinct _first_ question with example, input, and expected output, fantastic `x[nchar(gsub('^.*\\.', '', x$col2)) == 2, ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
x$col1[grep('\\..{2}$', x$col2)]
#[1] A C
#Levels: A B C
```